# How To Draw the Oval Shape Layer to the UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to draw the Oval shape to my textfield , I don't know how to draw using layer, if anyone help me for this design shadow,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Objective-C translation of Anton's answer since question is tagged for Objective-C and not Swift:

```
CAShapeLayer *shadowLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shadowLayer.fillColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
shadowLayer.lineWidth = 0.0f;
CGSize shadowSize = CGSizeMake(textField.bounds.size.width + 40, 40);
CGRect shawdowBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, shadowSize.width, shadowSize.height);
shadowLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:shawdowBounds].CGPath;
shadowLayer.bounds = shawdowBounds;
shadowLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(textField.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(textField.bounds));
[containerView.layer insertSublayer:shadowLayer atIndex0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code as an example:

```
let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
// set your shadow color here
shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor 
shadowLayer.lineWidth = 0
// calc size of your shadow according to your design
let shadowSize = CGSize(width: textField.bounds.width + 40, height: 20)
let shadowBounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: shadowSize)
shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: shadowBounds).cgPath
shadowLayer.bounds = shadowBounds
shadowLayer.position = CGPoint(x: textField.bounds.midX, y: textField.bounds.maxY)
containerView.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
```

Here I assume that you have some `containerView`, containing your text field as a subview and keep reference to the text field in variable called `textField`.